# Char by Char looping replacing in BASH

Tags: linux, string, bash, loops, replace

So I've made a little piece of code that SHOULD replace underscores (_) with a character from another string. In case you're wondering the purpose, I intend to make the game of Hangman.

```
x=0
while [ $x -lt $LengthOfAnswer ]; do
  if [ $Answer:$x:1 == $GuessedChar ]; then
    Underscores=$( echo $Underscores | sed s/_/${Answer:$x:1}/$((x+1)) )
  fi
done
```

The result from this is that the first time a a guess is made, and therefore this loop goes off, everything works as intended.
After that however, the result starts to take strange patterns.

Example:

> Answer is "abcdef"
>
> Start: "_ _ _ _ _ _"
>
> Guess "a": "a _ _ _ _ _"
>
> Guess "b": "a _ b _ _ _"
>
> Guess "c": "a _ b _ c _"

Of course, at that point it SHOULD be "a b c _ _ _"

If anyone has a suggestion on what needs to be done to get this working, I'd gladly hear it. And if there is no other option but to change my structure, then please do tell me.

Comment: You can find an implementation of a hangman game made in bash [here](https://github.com/higuaro/bash-games/blob/master/hang.sh)

Comment: Well, there is an assessment going on at my university where we all need to make Hangman as a test of our skills in bash. Structure wise this is a breeze, but the language itself here is the big blockage most run into.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to higuaro for this one, with his link;
 [Hangman Example](https://github.com/higuaro/bash-games/blob/master/hang.sh)

The extra bit of context helped me figure this one out, coming to the following solution:

```
x=0
while [ $x -lt $LengthOfAnswer ]; do
  if [ $Answer:$x:1 == $GuessedChar ]; then
    Underscores="${Underscores:0:$x}$GuessedChar${Underscores:$((x+1))}"
  fi
  let "x++"
done
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop ? you arent making x higher so it wont reach $lengthOfAnswer

Answer (score 0):

Try using sed, solution to many problems. See the next code as a starting point.

```
secret="a b c d e f"
guess="a"

echo "${secret}" | sed 's/[^'${guess}' ]/_/g'

# add each new guess to the quess string. Assume after trying "a", first "p" and "q" is tried before "b" is tried
guess="apqb"
echo "${secret}" | sed 's/[^'${guess}' ]/_/g'
```

All you need to do is reading input from the player and checking for valid input (one char, not space, underscore or something like that).

Comment: I just found another nice solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444814/bash-show-charcaters-if-not-in-string