# Get remaining letters in shell/terminal from alphabet which aren't used

Tags: bash, terminal

I try to make a hangman game in terminal
I want do display the char's which aren't used yet, example:
User has given the char's: A, B, C & D. 
I want to show: "chars left: EFGHIJKLM....."

My Code:

```
for x in {a..z}
do
    if [ "$x" != "$GUESSED" ]; then 
        LETTERSLEFT="$LETTERSLEFT $x"    
    fi
done
}
```

What I try to do:
If $x not in the guessed answer, add this to $lettersleft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simple shell script (tested in bash) reads a character from a user and then outputs the guessed and left letters

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter character:"
read GUESSED

for x in {a..z}
do
    if [[ "$GUESSED" != *"$x"* ]]
    then
        LETTERSLEFT="$LETTERSLEFT$x"
    fi
done
echo "Letters left:" $LETTERSLEFT
echo "Letters guessed:" $GUESSED
```

Console output

```
Enter character:
s
Letters left: abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz
Letters guessed: s
```

Hope this helps

Comment: is there something possible with SED, like: sed 's/input//' string. ? to remove the letters

Comment: You could try something like this example - `echo abcdefg | tr -d g`, it deletes the letter 'g' and gives you 'abcdef'

Comment: @M1Ö A solution with `sed` is slower than `tr`or a solution like http://stackoverflow.com/a/29445540/3220113. It is possible: `deleteChar='x'; echo "${lettersLeft}" | sed 's/'"${deleteChar}"'//g'`.

Comment: Thanks all, I used the method of @vmachan